# JavaScript - standard in using new key word

Tags: javascript, memory, var

This is a question which is related to memory usage and "new" keyword. I need your suggesions and preferences for using "new" in local methods.

```
get: function ()
{
    var get = new Ajax.Updater('resourceList',
    "url",
    {
        method: 'POST',
        onComplete: this._onComplete.bind(this)
    });
}
```

In the above code, I am assigning the object to a local variable which is not used anywhere, I can write the code in the following way also

```
get: function ()
{
    new Ajax.Updater('resourceList',
    "url",
    {
        method: 'POST',
        onComplete: this._onComplete.bind(this)
    });
}
```

Here I am not assigning the object to any variable.

I am little confused now. Which way is better, assigning to a variable or not assigning to a variable? If I assign to a variable after the local method scope the object will be taken off from memory, but if I don't assign what will happen? Will it be taken care of by garbage collection? What is Which is the best way of doing it ? Personally I prefer to assign to a variable; is that correct? when will the object get destroyed if I am not assigning to a variable?

Comment: I'd argue that a constructor isn't as appropriate as a function that defines private variables and accepts the same arguments. What's the point of constructing something that you don't need to reference?

Comment: You caused us some problem in understanding your code :P http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117654/in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

JavaScripts garbage collector will process items as they fall out of scope, and are no longer reachable; this will be true for your `Ajax.Updater` object regardless of whether you assign it to a variable or not.

So as to whether you should assign it to a variable or not? **I wouldn't**. It makes it clear that nothing else refers to that object again. If you assign it to a variable, people will start looking to see where that variable is used.

The garbage collector is *very* clever and intelligent. You seldom need to worry about whether the garbage collector will pick up something or not. In 99.99999999% cases, it will.

Answer (score 0):

You should only assign it to a variable if you subsequently need access to the object. Either way the object will be garbage collected, so you may as well save yourself a variable declaration and a few bytes.