# ** in javascript?

Tags: javascript

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117503/javascript-standard-in-using-new-key-word#11117553) shows the usage of `**var = new Object();` and that's something totally new for me.

Since I didn't notice in any of the answers, that the double-star is not something JS related, question arose.

**What is the double-star `**` used for in JavaScript?**

Comment: It's a syntax error. It's not part of JavaScript... He's only using it to show what part of the code he's referring to in his comment afterwards ;)

Comment: my be he was trying /* to start a comment

Comment: He just want to point out his code. ** here has no meaning at all :)

Comment: I can't think of a reason, all I get, in response to `**var = new Date();` (as an example) is `SyntaxError: Unexpected token *`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing.

In that context it means "I am failing to add bold text to a code section in Markdown"

Comment: I wonder if that should be added as a description of `**` in markdown as a subsection of how to, or rather *not* to, embed code :)